# absolute position and responsive grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, css-position, positioning

I want to give some image absolute position inside a grid cell .when I use absolute position for images and relative position for their parents ( which is a grid cell), the parent width becomes zero so images become disappear. I can fix it with giving it min-width:100% to image parent container but when I decrease browser's width and the grid became 1 column then background that I gave to parent disappear. my quesiton is can I fix it in a better way?
here is an image of what I want to do with this code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N94ze.jpg) and here is code in codepen:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/alisafaeyan/pen/ZEvNmMM)

and code in here: Thanks in advance

```css
.section-about{
  padding:2rem;
  background:gray;
}
.grid-2-col {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  justify-items: center; 
}
.section-about__text{
  background-color:green
}
.composition {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color:red}
.composition__photo {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
}
.composition__photo--p1 {
      top: 0.5rem;
      left: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-about">
  <div class="grid-2-col">
    <div class="section-about__text">
      <p class="paragraph">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam
              impedit laudantium autem itaque eligendi asperiores aspernatur
              quisquam nesciunt modi, nemo aliquam. Saepe molestiae numquam
              vitae eveniet autem laborum voluptas maxime.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="composition">
      <img
       class="composition__photo composition__photo--p1"
       src=""https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475669698648-2f144fcaaeb1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80""
         />

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why give the images in the composition absolute positioning? If you do the grid won't be able to pick up the requisite height for that cell. Try position: relative.

Comment: Hi my friend.I attached a photo I want to position my images like that photo so I need absolute position inside the gird cell. do you mean I give position: relative instead of absolute??

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why you need absolute, in fact I believe you don't because you need the grid to pick up the height it has to make that cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/qBpzPRX

The important bits are that:

- you use position: relative for the images
- then you play with their top and left values
- you use relative units for these top and left values, eg %
- I found it useful to add some padding to .composition, there are probably other ways to achieve the same result though
- adding a margin-bottom to the images helped me fix layout issues at some viewports

**CSS**

```
.section-about{
  padding:2rem;
  background:gray;
}
.grid-2-col {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  justify-items: center; 
}
.section-about__text{
  background-color:green
}
.composition {
  position: relative;
/*   min-width: 100%; */
  background-color:red;
  padding:5% 0 10%;
}
.composition__photo {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 30%;
/*     position: absolute; */
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.composition__photo--p1 {
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}

.composition__photo--p2 {
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
}

.composition__photo--p3 {
  top: 45%;
  left: -45%;
}
```

Comment: thanks dear David.that worked.I just didnt understand why did you give .composition class a position: relative it doesnt move and there is no absolute position for its children.Also you used position relative for images its relative to what? is it consider relative to its parent which is .composition?

Comment: Hi @ali  .composition class doesn't need to use position: relative. It was in your initial codepen and I hadn't noticed it. Using position relative for the images is the most important bit of the puzzle. It moves them relative to where they would normally. Usually the 3 images would be side by side.  What I've done with position: relative and setting the top and left values is move the first image down and to the right a little, moved the second one down a lot and to the right a little, and the moved the third one down even more, and this time I moved it to the left so it overlaps the other 2